# Dynamically created autocompletetextview shows only selected row after orientation change

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to create an AutoCompleteTextView dynamically for use like a spinner in Android. I have made it work properly with showing the dropdown list on click and on focus change. But when I change orientation after selecting any option, only the selected option is shown in the dropdown after that.

Is there any way to correct this and make it show all the items after orientation change as well? I found one way which is to `setText("")` everytime but this also clears any selected value which is undesirable.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently had a need to do something similar myself. I did this with a custom adapter that overrides the getFilter() which returns null (so that it returns all available values).

```
public class AutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public AutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```